# How to solve $\int_C Im(z) dz$ where $C$ is the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I want to solve $\int_C Im(z) dz$ where $C$ is the unit circle. The first thing is to parameterize the curve, $C$:
$$
z(t)=e^{it}
$$
where $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$

Then
$$
\frac {dz}{dt} = ie^{it}
$$

and:
$$
f(z(t)) = Im(z(t)) = Im(e^{it})=Im(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))=i\sin(t)
$$

Then
$\int_C f(z) dz$ = $\int\limits_{a}^{b} f(z(t))\cdot z'(t)dt = \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} i\sin(t)\cdot ie^{it}dt = -\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \sin(t)\cdot e^{it} dt$

Let $I = \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \sin(t)\cdot e^{it} dt$, by integration by parts:
$$
u=sin(t)
$$
$$
du = cos(t)dt
$$
$$
dv=e^{it}dt
$$
$$
v=\frac{1}{i}e^{it}
$$

And then
$$
-I=\frac{1}{i}\sin(t)\cdot e^{it}-\frac{1}{i}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \cos(t)\cdot e^{it} dt
$$

By another integration by parts:

$$
u=\cos(t)
$$
$$
du = -\sin(t)dt
$$
$$
dv=e^{it}dt
$$
$$
v=\frac{1}{i}e^{it}
$$

At the end:
$$
-I=\frac 1i\sin(t)\cdot e^{it}-\frac 1i(\frac 1i\cos(t)e^{it}+\frac 1iI)
$$
$$
-I=\frac 1i\sin(t)\cdot e^{it}+\cos(t)e^{it}+I
$$

$$
I=\frac {\frac 1i\sin(t)\cdot e^{it}+cos(t)\cdot e^{it}}{-2}
$$

and if I substitude $2\pi$ and $0$:
$$
-\frac 12-\frac 12=0
$$
But the book expect the answer be $-\pi$. What's wrong about my solution? Another question I have is that $Im(z)$ is analytic in everywhere and $C$ (the unit circle) is a closed path, so according to cauchy's integral theorem, the integral should be $0$, isn't that right?

Comment: $\Im(z(t)) = \sin(t)$ no?

Comment: @IsmailBello, Thank you very much. Yes, but at the end, the integral would become $I-I=\frac 1ie^{it}\sin(t)+e^{it}\cos(t)$ which is equal to zero?

Comment: I dont think it should be zero, since $\int{\sin(t)e^{it}} = \int{\sin(t)\cos(t) + i\sin^2(t)} = \int{\frac{\sin(2t)}{2} + i\sin^2(t)}$ the real part vanishes but the second doesnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to integrate by parts here without making some small unnecessary mistakes. (For example, the left hand side after your first integration should be $I$, not $-I$.)

A simpler approach is:

\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \operatorname{Im}(z(t)) z'(t)\,dt &= 
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i} \cdot ie^{it} \,dt \\
&= \frac12\int_0^{2\pi} (e^{2it}-1)\,dt \\
&= \frac12 \left[ \frac{e^{2it}}{2i}-t \right]_0^{2\pi} = -\pi.
\end{align}

As for your final question $ \operatorname{Im}(z)$ is in fact **nowhere** analytic.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\Im(e^{it})\,de^{it}=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(t)ie^{it}dt=i\int_0^{2\pi}(\sin(t)\cos(t)+i\sin^2(t))dt=i2\pi i\frac12=-\pi,$$
by taking the average values of the trigonometric expressions.